# spring-boot-maven-plugin not pulling in dependent classes into jar

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Im having a problem with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` whereby it is not including the dependent classes in the resulting jar file.

In the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html), it states that dependencies with scope `provided` will be included in the jar file, but I cant get it to include them.

I have a project with 2 sub-modules: `model` and `restServer`. In the `model` module, I want to use swagger to codegen based on an openApi input model. The resulting classes are put in a jar file: `model/target/rest-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

In the `restServer` module, I have the Spring RestController and Application java code, and want to "pull in" the `model` classes into the resulting jar file: `restServer/target/rest-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` builder, but its not including anything from the `model` sub-module.

The entire project structure and pom files are listed below.

How can I get the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to pull in the class files from the `model` sub-module, effectively creating a "fat" self-contained jar?

Project Structure

```
project-root/
    pom.xml # parent pom
    model/
        pom.xml
        src/main/openApi/model.json
        target/
            generated-sources/* (package: com.me.rest.model.*)
            rest-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

    restServer/
        pom.xml
        src/main/java/com/me/rest/
            controller/Controller.java
            Application.java
```

Parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.me</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>rest</name>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <description>Swagger codegen for Spring Rest Server sandbox project</description>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen</url>
  </scm>

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>2.2.0</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <modules>
    <module>model</module>
    <module>restServer</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

model/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.kontron</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.kontron</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-model</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies> ... </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Swagger codegen plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration> ... </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

restServer/pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
      <groupId>com.kontron</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-parent</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>rest-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.kontron</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>     <!-- Notice scope is provided -->
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Update: adding resulting META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: rest-server
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Built-By: bjohnson
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.me
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.1.2.RELEASE
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.me.rest.Application
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.5.4
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_144
Implementation-URL: https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#/spring-bo
 ot-starter-parent/rest-parent/rest-server
```

Comment: The dependencies are placed in BOOT-INF\lib\ did you check this folder in your JAR?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Wow, looks like it is indeed there! I was looking for the class structure "com/me/rest/...". Using "jar tf" I see BOOT-INF/lib/rest-model-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. I guess the rest of the classes in the jar can use that, right?

Comment: Yes I added this as the answer. Thank you for accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependencies are placed in BOOT-INF\lib\ of the repackaged JAR file.

This path will be added to the classpath of you Spring Boot Application.

Comment: I added an update with the Manifest. Should I see the path there, or is it handled internally?

Comment: No because Spring Boot has it's own class loader